# Backbone Template - Collection Sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

If I have a list of products I'm getting that has a "type", "name", and "description"... and I want to have a view where the products are grouped together by type. How would I do that? Right now I'm dynamically building the HTML with jQuery by looping through the array of products, sorting them by type, then looping through it again and building the HTML. I'd much rather have the HTML code in a template and have each product being a Backbone view so I can better manage events and etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone collections are automatically sorted, all you need to do is add a comparator (http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator).

This would looks something like:

```
var ProductCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  comparator: 'type'
})
```